# Reordering pairs of values within an array so they are in sequence

Tags: python, c, sorting

I'm trying to build a solution to properly order an array of value pairs so that they end up in the correct sequence. Consider this example in Python:

```
theArray = [['Dempster St','Main St'],['Dempster St','Church St'],['Emerson St','Church St']]
```

I need to order the array so that in the end it looks like this:

```
theArray = [['Emerson St','Church St'],['Church St','Dempster St'],['Dempster St','Main St']]
```

Some considerations:

- There is no guarantee that the order within each pair point in the same direction. Ex: in the example above, the second array element has the order of their pairs pointing in the opposite direction of the rest (Dempster to Church instead of Church to Dempster)
- The code should be built so that it could be used in both Python and C, so ideally it should be done without any language-specific tricks
- At the end, it doesn't matter in which order the final array will be built, as long as the elements follow the correct order. For example, the solution below would also work:

  `theArray = [['Main St','Dempster St'],['Dempster St','Church St'],['Church St','Emerson St']]`

Ideas?

Comment: as always, what have you tried?

Comment: I tried a nested loop with two counters. But even though I was able to connect some pairs of elements, I couldn't get them all as the order of some of them is the opposite.

Comment: @wotaskd Show the code for the nested loop.

Comment: You basically have a directed graph; use graph algorithms to find yourself a path.

Comment: Can we assume every street is at most mentioned twice, (and two exactly once), or do you need a more general solution? @Martijn Pieters it seems an undirected graph works for him, too (I think)

Comment: I don't have time to make my answer work for the undirected case too, so I'll make it a comment instead: if you consider each street as a node in a graph, and each pair an edge, then your problem reduces to finding an Eulerian path through the graph.  Searching for "Eulerian path undirected graph" should be fruitful.

Comment: Your problem is somewhat underspecified; you don't go anywhere near defining "correct sequence". Are pairs of streets to be interpreted as intersections, with `[A,B]` meaning exactly the same as `[B,A]`? Are you assuming that the streets form a rectangular grid? That there are no streets with one-way sections? What happens if you add `['Main St', 'Emerson St']` to your list?

Comment: I managed to make it work. I iterated each element of every pair with each other by using multiple nested loops - so that I could check for their uniqueness (and in order to do that, I increment an associated variable whenever an item was found more than once, like a refcount); at the end, the two elements with the lowest count are beginning and end of the route. From there it was quite easy to find the remaining connections.

Comment: @wotaskd Can you enter that comment, perhaps with some more detail, as an answer and mark it correct?

Comment: @wotaskd: as John Machin pointed out, your problem is underspecified. For example, `[['Emerson St','Church St'], ['Church St','Dempster St'], ['Dempster St','Main St']]` also seems to be a valid solution. If, OTOH, you'd define a starting point, eg. `'Main St'` , then this ambiguity would go away.

Comment: @pillmuncher Not really. It was item #3 on my list of considerations. See above. Any of the two directions is valid and that's acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work. I iterated each element of every pair with each other by using multiple nested loops - so that I could check for their uniqueness (and in order to do that, I increment an associated variable whenever an item was found more than once, like a refcount); at the end, the two elements with the lowest count are beginning and end of the route. From there it was quite easy to find the remaining connections.